# Wait till the file Save complete in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, file-upload

I have a file upload process in my asp.net C# application.
I am using the below code to save the browse file on path:

```
    this.fupUploadImage.SaveAs("filepath");
```

I have to wait the execution till the Save process completed. Can any body suggest the good approach ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since this doesnt look like a async method I assume that the file is saved when the method returns. So what execution you want to wait for?

Answer (score 1):

[SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas(v=vs.110).aspx) is a void method so you can wrap that call and return a value when it finishes

```
int SaveFile(string filePath)
      {            

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)) 
        {
            try{
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);
                return 1;
            }
            catch{

            } 

          return 0;
        }


      }
```

then you can cal it in this way

```
if (SaveFile(@"myPath/test.txt") > 0){
     //save ok!
}
```

this is a Synch approach to your problem. The program waits for the end of the Save process.
If you want to execute it in background in another task you can call

```
   Task<int> t = Task.Run(() => SaveFile(@"myPath/test.txt"))
                              .ContinueWith((i) => i > 0? "saveOk" : "saveFailed");
```

now the save operation is executed in background and at the end the result arrives in input in [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx) method and you can replace my labels `"saveOk"` and `"saveFailed"` with code to manage when save operation is succesfull or not.